# Can an induction cooktop be powered by a common inverter?

Tags: power-supply

I have purchased an induction cooktop (Prestige, model: PIC 12: 1500 watt) for domestic use.

In our area power cut is a common matter. So we have 150Ah tubuler battery powered inverter of Su-kam company whose model no. is SHINY 900 for the entire house. My humble question is 'Can an induction cooktop be powered by a common inverter as described above?'

Comment: What's the rated power output of your Su-kam SHINY 900? What the rated power output of your 150Ah tubeler battery (or voltage, and max rated current, from which power can be computed)?

Comment: It's very nice that you are so polite, but removing all the no-technical chatter makes your question shorter, and thus, better. That's the style we prefer here!

Comment: depending on how it's driven, you might be able to run it on low or med...

Comment: Buy a butane gas stove to cook without power.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is a solid **NO**.

That "Shiny 900" inverter is not only shiny but can only deliver 900 W, which would explain the "900" in it's name.

Your induction cooker requires 1500 W which is **much more** than that 900 W the Shiny can provide.

For a 1500 W cooker you really should be looking at 2000 W inverters (to have a bit of margin for that 1500 W) and maybe also a larger battery. 1500 W is **a lot** of power for a battery + inverter.

Comment: Dear Sir, Thank you very much for your kind answer. Actually, as per the specifications given in the manual, the induction cooktop starts working at 1000 w initially, and it can be increased up to 1500w or lowered down to even 500w. So, can I use the cooktop at 500w level when it is powered by the inverter? Please guide me. Best Regards, Shekhar

Comment: That is probably a **NO** as well. I expect that the cooker, when used at 500 W, will not actually lower it's power to 500 W **but** it will switch on/off so that **on average** it will consume 500 W. So for example 5 seconds on, 10 seconds off, then 5 seconds on again etc.... On average that's 500 W. Microwave ovens do this also. For cooking it is not an issue due to the heat capacity of pans and food. For the inverter it is, you simply cannot exceed that 900 W, a fuse might blow or it will be damaged.